# remove quotes from variable in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, phpjs

I really don't understand Javascript.

In PHP, I can remove quotes like this:

```
$tags_array = preg_replace('/"/', '', $tags_array);
```

How do I write it in Javascript?

Comment: Do you mean "remove quote from an array of string"? You'll have to loop through the array to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str = str.replace(/"/g, '');
```

Comment: The quote doesn't needs to be escaped, `/"/g` will be enough :)

Comment: PHP's `preg_replace` accepts array of strings or a single string, so `.replace` is not a direct replacement for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do almost the same thing with javascript what you  do with php, i mean many functions, here is the solution:

[PHPJS](http://phpjs.org/)